# Can same id be assign to two elements if they are use only one at a time?

Tags: javascript, html

```
if(condition)
     <span id="same">check1</span>
else
     <span id="same">check2</span>
```

Will the id be affected when I use it on JavaScript?

Comment: If they only exist on the page one at a time....

Comment: Yes, you can use the same `id` as long as only one actually exists within the page at the time.

Comment: Your example doesn't provide enough information for us to give you a proper answer. What does `if (element) else {element}` mean, exactly? If it's *creating* one element or the other, then that's fine. If it's *referencing* one or the other, then it is not fine.

Comment: Ok thanks for the answer

Comment: Is this plain JavaScript, or are you using some framework?

Comment: @trincot it's a plain JavaScript... No jQuery

Comment: IDs are made to be a UNIQUE identifier. Use classes when you want to have more than one, like that it's very bad way of coding. Or another logic on ids like on the one id="same1" and on the other id="same2" and then detect it with js and do same/different actions

Comment: @Lycidias you're talking about something different. OP is referring to adding an ID to multiple elements depending on a conditional, as long as you only create one instance of the element you should be fine.

Comment: You can do only if at a time only one html element is there in dom.

Comment: If this is plain JavaScript, then it has the wrong syntax. You cannot mix HTML with `if` like that. Could you post the code that you actually tried with?